# Can I create a custom decorator for a model method in Django?

Tags: python, django, model, decorator

Let's say I have the following model -

```
class Banana(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_banana(self):
        return f'Banana: {self.name}'
```

Now I want to add a logger that generates a log whenever the method starts and ends successfully to this `get_banana` method.

The logger is as follows -

```
class Log(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

So I create a logger decorator -

```
def log_status(f):
    def wrapper(**fields):
        Log.objects.create(**{k: (v if k != 'message' else v + ':STARTED') for k, v in fields.items()})
        return_value = f()
        Log.objects.create(**{k: (v if k != 'message' else v + ':COMPLETED') for k, v in fields.items()})

        return return_value
    return wrapper
```

How can I add this decorator to my `get_banana` method?

The following doesn't work because it can't see `self`.

```
@log_status(type='info', message='Get Banana.', content_object=self)
def get_banana(self):
    return f'Banana: {self.state}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are decorating a method, `self` is actually available to the decorator. It will not be available at parse time, but will definitely be available at run time. All you need to do is the change the decorator like this:

```
def log_status(function):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return_value = function(self, *args, **kwargs) # do whatever you want here
        return return_value
    return wrapper
```

That's all. Now at run time, self will be available to the decorator and will get passed to it and your function should execute as expected.